# Global Extrema on a Multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say there is a function $f(x, y) = x^3 + e^{3 y} - 3 x e^y$ . How can I deduce which components are the dominating factors of $f(x,y)$ and how to deduce whether $f(x,y)$ may have maximum or minimum values by just observing the dominating factors of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Read your notes, and read your text.  Just requires a bit of due diligence from you.

Comment: If it helps, you may want to substitute $z=e^y$ and so you need to analyse the function $x^3+z^3-3xz$ - however the domain is now $x, z\in\mathbb R, z>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $y$ values the dominant term is $e^{3y}$ and there is no abs  max. For negative $y$ values the dominant term is $x^3$ and there no abs min.

There is a local minimum, though, at $(1,0)$

First derivatives are zero when
$$
\begin{cases}
3 x^2-3 e^y=0\\
3 e^{3 y}-3 x e^y=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$H(x,y)=\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 6 x & -3 e^y \\
 -3 e^y & 9 e^{3 y}-3 x e^y \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$\det(H(x,y))=-18 x^2 e^y+54 x e^{3 y}-9 e^{2 y};\;\det(H(1,0))=27>0$$
The determinant of the Hessian matrix is negative at $(1,0)$, therefore it is a local minimum.

Comment: Did you mean to say for  positive z values instead of  positive y values?

Comment: No I mean that when $y>0$ then $e^{3y}$ has the largest value. For instance, computing $f(10,10)$, we have $$\left\{e^{3 y},-3 x e^y,x^3\right\}=\{1.07\times 10^{13},-660793,1000\}$$ while for $f(-10,-10)$ we have $$\left\{9.36 \times{10^{-14}},0.001,-1000\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.